# Lie group of a complex simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

The context: I have a complex simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The book I'm reading states

"Let $G$ be the connected simply-connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$."

What is meant by these words? I have read about Lie's third theorem, but that holds for real Lie algebra. How does this work for complex Lie algebras? This is what I think might work:

- I have read somewhere that every (semi)simple Lie algebra is the complexification of a real one, let's denote it by $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$
- by Lie's third theorem we have a connected simply-connected Lie group $G_{\mathbb{R}}$ whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{R}}$
- now what? I have read that the notion of complexification of a Lie group is not as "trivial" as the algebra case, so I wouldn't know how to continue.

Is this (at least the first two points) correct?

Related question: I had a course in which we defined $G = \operatorname{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ as the group generated by $e^{\operatorname{ad}x}$ for all $\operatorname{ad}$-nilpotent $x\in \mathfrak{g}$. I suppose this is related to my question (the professor vaguely mentioned something about it being "the smallest Lie group which has $\mathfrak{g}$ as its Lie algebra" and also an algebraic group), but I can't connect the dots.

Thanks in advance for your answers, I'm sure they will be helpful.

Comment: "What is meant by these words? " Actually, just this: take one of the complex simple Lie algebras from the classification of type $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n, G_2,F_4,E_6,E_7,E_8$. Then there is a unique connected simply connected Lie group $G$ with this Lie algebra. You do not need real forms for this, also not Lie's third theorem. The Lie groups are just the well known matrix groups, e.g., $SL_n(\Bbb C)$, for type $A_{n-1}$ and so on. The wikipedia article on [simple Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group) might be helpful.

Comment: You are asking about Lie's third theorem - yes, this is also true over complex numbers, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905046/construction-of-the-simply-connected-lie-group-of-a-given-lie-algebra). But for *simple* Lie algebras, we can do this much easier than in the general case. Note that the adjoint representation of the Lie algebra then is faithful, i.e., we have linear Lie algebras and linear Lie groups.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so for the groups which aren't simply connected do I just take the universal cover?

Comment: Regarding your second comment: yes, that's something I was thinking about too, as $\mathfrak{g}$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{g})$. So in this case can I just take the Lie group associated to the matrix algebra $\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{g})$? Also, what is the meaning of Lie group in this context? The same as Lie group but replacing "manifold" with "complex manifold"?

Comment: You mean what a complex Lie group is? Yes, a complex manifold such that the group operations are holomorphic. You should have a definition in your lecture notes.

Comment: And over $\Bbb C$, many matrix groups are already simply connected, contrary to the case over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Note complex Lie groups are still real Lie groups just with the addition of a compatible complex structure so in some sense we don't need a separate definition here. If you read something is for real Lie groups/algebras, unless you think they specifically mean non-complex, then it applies to both.

Comment: For the second part of your question, the fact that there is a unique simply connected group $\tilde{G}$ with  means that it is the universal cover of every other connected group with that Lie algebra.  Conversely, every such group is a quotient of $\tilde{G}$ (by a discrete subgroup of the centre). At the other end of the scale we have the adjoint group $\mathrm{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ which in the semisimple case can also be described as the quotient by the whole centre of the simply connected (or any of the quotients in between) and so here at least you can easily see it is the "smallest".